# Where to find the Xamarin.Forms.Core dll for Download

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I've been looking everywhere, already tried nuget, Google, but can't find the Xamarin.Forms.Core dll to add to my project.

Does anyone know where I can find her?

Comment: Xamarin.Forms.Core is part of the Xamarin.Forms nuget package - https://www.fuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: I know once upon a time when DLL's where looking like independent units to pull out of the Internet. This was never the reality and certainly these days you should fight the urge to download single DLL's and instead use NuGet or other means (installers maybe) to get the DLL together with its dependencies

Comment: @Jason, sorry for my ignorance on the subject, if the Xamarin dll, Forms.Core.dll, is already in Xamarin.Forms, then I don't need to add Xamarin, Forms.Core.dll to my project right?

Comment: No.  You should be using nuget to add XF to your project, not individually managing dlls

Comment: it is part of the Xamarin Forms nuget package. Install Xamarin.Forms from Nuget on each of these projects. If its already installed, reinstall it.